# How to use numpy to compare several arrays and identify the one with minimal differences?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, ocr

I do have a set of arrays (20x40) with values between 0 and 255 (grayscale images).

I need to compare a given array with a set of 10 others that are used as reference and choose the one that is closest to the given image.

I know that this looks like OCR but in this case OCR is not able to anything good.

I already tried to compute `abs(x-y)` but the results where not good enough.

Capture:

[image: real]

Reference:

[image: reference]

Answer (score 1):

I have been solving a similar problem at bskyb with OCRing frames taken from a video stream.

I ended up creating a dictionary of coordinates for each digit in the image `(x,y, w, h)` and wrote a script that generated hundreds of those digits and saved them as masks. One of the testers then selected the best masks (the least distorted ones) and saved them as 1.bmp for digit 1, 2.bmb for digit 2...

We had to create 18 different image for each digit to supports the various resolutions, aspect_ratios we have. Those masks then were loaded into a dictionary at the start of the OCR process. We stored the images as a numpy array.

```
def load_samples(parent_dir=r'c:\masks'):
"""Loads the OCR samples of all digits of all possible variations into
memory.
"""
m = dict() # m is our map, a dict of lists of numpy arrays
for d in os.listdir(parent_dir):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(parent_dir, d)):
        continue
    m[d] = []
    for i in range(10): # 10 images [0..9]
        filename = os.path.join(parent_dir, d, '%d.bmp'%i)
        m[d].append(imread(filename))
return m
```

Then for every image we read, we divide it into digits by converting the digit into a numpy array and compareing it with all the masks we have to find the closest match and select it based on that. digits_map is what is being returned from the load_samples above.

```
def image2digit(image, digits_map, video_args):
"""Our home made OCR, we compare each image of digit with 10 images of all
possible digits [0..10] and return the closest match.
"""
def absdiff(img1, img2):
    func = numpy.vectorize(lambda a, b: abs(int(a)-int(b)))
    v = func(img1, img2)
    w = coordinates[video_args]['w']
    h = coordinates[video_args]['h']
    return numpy.sum(v)/(w*h) # takes the average

# convert the image to a numpy array
image_array = fromimage(image) # from scipy.misc
# compare it with all variations
scores = []
for (i, ir) in enumerate(digits_map[video_args]):
    scores.append(absdiff(ir, image_array))
# return the best match as a string
index = numpy.argmin(scores)
return str(index)
```

This worked well for us except in some distorted frames where 6 is OCRed as 5. I'm experimenting with transforming the images into grey scale before comparison to see if that helps with the distorted images problem.

Comment: It is the *same* problem, take care! ... I mean it!

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the pixels together and then take the sum of all pixels:

- ((0,0) of image 1 * (0,0) of image 2) + ((0,1) of image 1 * (0,1) of image 2) + ...

This is like the [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) with no offset.  ([scipy.signal.correlate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate.html#scipy.signal.correlate))

The command in numpy would just be

```
sum(a * b)
```

There's probably a name for this, but I don't know what it is.

I'm guessing you're going to compare the reference digits one by one with a measured image to see which digit it is?

You'd have to compare the reference digits with themselves first to find out what a perfect match looks like, and normalize each one by this to get the similarity.  An imperfect match will be a value less than this.  For instance:

```
0 1 3
1 2 3
2 0 0
```

will produce 28 when compared with itself, but will produce 25 when compared with

```
0 1 3
0 2 3
1 0 0
```

So your match would be 25/28 = 0.89.  So you know that the second image is close, but not the same